# X11 forwarding issue Ubuntu 12.10 from AIX

Tags: 12.10, command-line, server, ssh

Using ubuntu 12.10 and have putty installed, I am using ssh /putty to connect an AIX system once I do that I export the display and run something simple like 'xclock' or 'xterm'

Problem is its not working, I get the following 'Error: Can't open display:'

I have checked on the server side and on my laptop to make sure X11forwarding is enabled and it is within putty,

```
ssh_config (local) : ForwardX11 yes
                     ForwardX11Trusted yes

sshd_config (AIX Server) : X11Forwarding yes
```

I have tried connecting through Putty,and from the CLI

```
ssh -X user@<Aix_Server>
```

But no matter what I try I get the : Error: Can't open display: message
This was working for me, but not since I have migrated to 12.10

Anyone out there come across this before have any suggestions?

**EDIT**

The below is from AIX after I login using Putty:

```
 echo $DISPLAY
 xclock Error: Can't open display: $
```

Comment: Ok the below is from AIX after I login using Putty. $ echo $DISPLAY $ xclock
Error: Can't open display:
$

Answer (score 1):

Ok it seems that the following has resolved the issue.

After looking at this for the last while it appears that the xauth location changed from AIX 5 , so it wasn't able to find it.

So when using sudo after that, I used the following :

```
sudo DISPLAY=localhost:0.0 XAUTHORITY=/home/{home_dir}/.Xauthority {command_here}
```

Worked and I was able to launch and get done / installed what I needed.

Thanks to @zwets your help was great, sometimes after looking at something for too long you need some fresh input.

Answer (score 0):

How about `ssh -Y user@server`?

Comment: Yeah tried both options ssh -Y and ssh -X but te same with both options.

Comment: @D1979 You say "I export the display". Using `ssh -X`, `-x` or `-Y` you shouldn't do that as the X11 output gets tunneled. Ssh will set it for you. What is the value of DISPLAY right after you login? What does `echo $DISPLAY` show?

Comment: And to isolate that this is not a client-end issue, does DISPLAY get set when you `ssh -Y localhost` on the Ubuntu end? (Note: you _are_ ssh-ing from a terminal window in the X environment, right? I once made the mistake to try and diagnose this from VT1.)

Comment: ssh -Y localhost when I try this I get the following : ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused I guess this is because I have not got openssh-server server installed. On my laptop I am using the ssh-agent to connect to the server.

Comment: OK, I assumed you had an ssh server running on your laptop. Everything seems in place (in fact, having `X11Forwarding yes` on the remote end normally suffices; the client options `ForwardX11*` are redundant with `-X/-Y`). Final check: do you have `xauth`?

Comment: Yeah, I am leaning more towards the server side as having the issue ,  will check the xauth list etc and see whats available and play around with this a little more. Maybe an upgrade did something with the xauth location. Will see